# How to list only files in first level subdirectories in Unix

Tags: unix

How to list only files in first level subdirectories in Unix. Suppose i have folders like this.

```
Folder1 > SubFolder1
        > SubFolder2
        > SubFolder3
```

I want to list only .csv files in all the subfolders

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Why not get the .csv files in *all* folders then exclude those in `Folder1`?

Comment: Anyways, ultimately if i get the list of files in the first level subfolders, that serves the purpose :) , Do you have command for that please ?\

Comment: I wasn't offering an answer - just asking why you didn't do that. I assumed that before asking the question you'd already done some research (searched on google, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

The normal approach is to use `find`. Note the sue of quotes:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 -name '*.csv'
```

The `-maxdepth 3` makes `find` only match items found at least 3 levels under the current directory and the `-mindepth 3` makes it ignore matches that are deeper than three. For example:

```
$ tree
.
|-- file.csv
`-- Folder1
    |-- file.csv
    |-- SubFolder1
    |   |-- file.csv
    |   `-- foo
    |       `-- file.csv
    |-- SubFolder2
    |   `-- file.csv
    `-- SubFolder3
        `-- file.csv

5 directories, 6 files
$ find . -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 -name '*.csv' 
./Folder1/SubFolder1/file.csv
./Folder1/SubFolder3/file.csv
./Folder1/SubFolder2/file.csv
```

If you only want the file names, not the full path, you could do

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 -name '*.csv' -exec basename {} \;
```

Or use find's `printf`:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 -name '*.csv' -printf "%f\n"
```

Of course, you can also do it directly using shell globbing:

```
$ ls */*/*.csv
Folder1/SubFolder1/file.csv  Folder1/SubFolder3/file.csv
Folder1/SubFolder2/file.csv
```

And to get the file names alone:

```
 $ for i in */*/*.csv; do basename "$i"; done
file.csv
file.csv
file.csv
```

Or

```
$ for i in */*/*.csv; do printf "%s\n" ${i##*/}; done
file.csv
file.csv
file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `find . -maxdepth 1 | grep csv`

Comment: I am getting this error: find: File system loop detected; `./.snapshot' is part of the same file system l                                                                                                                     oop as `.'.

Comment: Why use two commands when you can just use find . -maxdepth 2 -iname '*.csv' , which actually works and doesn't select abcsv.txt or csv-processor.cs, and maxdepth 1 doesn't even go into subdirectories.

Comment: @sami, I am just running find .-maxdepth 1 -iname '*.csv' , but getting this error.find: `.-maxdepth': No such file or directory
find: `1': No such file or directory
Let me know if anything wrong. do i have to change something here...

Comment: @Kriti You are missing space between . and -maxdepth (sorry, my mistake), but note that you need at least 2 for maxdepth.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, I tried this find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.csv', but dint work either, same old error..

Answer (score 0):

Something like `ls Folder1/*/*.csv` is probably what you're looking for.

With only filenames and nothing more, use `find . -maxdepth 2 -iname '*.html' -printf '%f\n'`

The maxdepth parameter defines how deeply to go into the folders. 1 would mean the current directory, 2 means one level deeper etc. Default is unlimited. Since you want files in a subdirectory, 2 is the correct value.

Comment: this is almost working, but in the results  I need only filenames not folders

Comment: please let me know if we can get only the filenames, not the folder path.

Comment: @Kriti  Appended another command, which prints only filenames.

Comment: cool... its working.. but along with list fo the filename its also printing the error we were getting earlier

Comment: this worked...'ls Folder1/*/*.csv | sed 's#.*/##'' from Mr Walter A... thanks for your response...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the path with sed. You can use # in sed so you do not have to escape the /.

```
ls Folder1/*/*.csv | sed 's#.*/##'
```

Comment: This will fail if any of the directory names contain newlines.